# set generic class type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

How can I set generic type? For example:

```
Class<List<Integer>> asd = List<Integer>.class \\ does not work
```

May be that is a bit stupid question, but I have never met a code where this thing was done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, what you want is `List.class`; the generic types are only available at compile-time, and are "erased" at run-time. There's a brief explanation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html 
...and a bit more detail here: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

Comment: Compiler has all information to check if type is correctly assigned or not. Why does it make me to use ugly suppress warnings annotations when I could (if it is supported by language of course) specify concrete type and not use raw generic Class. And then, ok, let type information be erased in runtime. But in source code why can not I have it specified?

Comment: In brief, the runtime type can't be checked, because the Class object (and the runtime environment that it reflects) doesn't have a slot for the generic type being filled-in, since in most (not all) cases, that can't be determined by the compiler for a Class-object… i.e. `List<Object>.class` would be `.equal` to `List<String>.class`, they both yield `Class<List> = List.class` … So even though in your example, `asd` would be of type `Class<List<Integer>>`, you could likewise use `asd` to hold `Class<String>` or something else. In the limited case where `asd` is `final`, you don't need `asd`…

Comment: You speak about runtime it is not important here. What important is to specify concrete type for generic class in _source_ code. That is the main point of my question. You see, I need no runtime capabilities here.

Comment: Well, put another way: the reason that there are no specifications for generic types in the Class type or .class notation, is because it would not matter to the code it creates. Or, seen differently: Class<List> expresses the methods and properties of *any* List, regardless of the specific type that it might be containing; and, as the signatures of those methods *compile into* types that take Object, you *could* (but *should not*) ignore the generic type specifications and e.g. push a String into a List<Integer> (and wreak havoc)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, due to [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure).  There's a number of hacks in various libraries to help out with reflection, but the language itself has generally poor support for introspection of generic types.

Comment: Compiler has all information to check if type is correctly assigned or not. Why does it make me to use ugly suppress warnings annotations when I could (if it is supported by language of course) specify concrete type and not use raw generic `Class`. And then, ok, let type information be erased in runtime. But in source code why can not I have it specified?